# How to make flexbox sibling shrink to prevent text wrap

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind, I have a `div` and two children that are `flexbox`. When the screen size gets small, the first child doesn't shrink to give its sibling room. How do I fix this?

When I add `flex-shrink-0` to the second child it overflows.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/UmXXkuJqk3?size=364x720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this because of the `input` tag as by default input tags have `minimum width` of `100%`.

To overcome this add `w-full` class inside the `input` tag.

Code: [tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ed2QU0UOjB?size=112x720)

---

##### Output (Before)

[image]

##### Output (After)

[image]